# Connecting to DMA radius manager and Managing Data

Tags: radius

I have a DMA Radius Manager with admin account. My company wants to create a custom application that autheticate with the DMA Radius Manager and manage data without accessing the web pannel. I'm wondering if it's possible, if yes can you please show me where to start maybe a small tutorial ?

I don't know if the idea is clear, Thank you.

Comment: working on a similar requirement... were you able to take this forward??

Comment: well i tried to make an automatic login by using html carving to fill the form and press the login button grammatically it didn't work too, if you can achieve the idea and share it with me it will be grateful, and I'm ready to work together, maybe we can reach a solution to this problem :), thank you!

Comment: reach me on lakshman.pilaka@gmail.com to move the discussion forward. I am more than willing to work together.

Comment: @LakshmanPilaka
What happened to you guys? Were you able to accomplish this project? I am building a RESTful API implementation for the DMA radius manager to be able to make a custom dashboard and custom functionalities that don't exist on the original DMA radius manager system. I successfully reached the point of being able to create a user. But it's just the start of the journey. I looked everywhere for a good solution. But we found DMA containing most of what we want, however it's closed source, so I needed to cross that way to add custom functionalities on top of the existing ones.